# recently i have tried to connect vite and firebase but at end i got this error i dont know to solve this

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vite

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sojTu.png)

This is error i got( i have attach the image too)

App.jsx:14 [2024-03-30T14:08:58.599Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.10.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:undefined' has been suspended.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
App.jsx:14
POST [https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/chann…t8bfxc&SID=zC0Bn075IIsrG1YXDo5VTA&RID=59161&TYPE=terminate&zx=y5k0pfa69yem](https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/chann%E2%80%A6t8bfxc&SID=zC0Bn075IIsrG1YXDo5VTA&RID=59161&TYPE=terminate&zx=y5k0pfa69yem) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
App.jsx:16 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.
App.jsx:16 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Failed to get document because the client is offline.

trying to solve the problem